# Applying different functions to same data using for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, igraph

I have a dataset, a graph. I want to apply several graph clustering methods with different parameters in R.

Is it possible to store name of graph clustering algorithms (from package igraph) in an array or a list then use it in a for loop.

Something like this:

```
algorithms <- c(igraph::cluster_walktrap,igraph::cluster_louvain,igraph::cluster_leiden)

for (i in 1:3) {
   result <- algorithms[i](data)
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `algorithms <- list(...)` rather than `algorithms <- c(...)` and then use `algorithms[[i]](data)` rather than `algorithms[i](data)`

Comment: @MrFlick I think `c` would work here too, though obviously it creates a list rather than a vector., so the main thing is to access its members with the double square brackets, as you say.

Comment: you need `algorithms[[i]](your_graph)` Note that `[i]` gives you back a list i while `[[i]]` gives you back the element at position i of the list

Comment: And it might be helpful to write the `result`s to a list rather than overwriting at each iteration of ther loop...